# Where can I switch off displaying messages from sub folders in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying out Outlook 2010 on my existing IMAP account. One thing that really annoys me is that after selecting a top-level folder I see all messages, also from subfolders. How can I switch this off? I can't find an appropriate option anywhere.

EDIT: This appears to be a different problem - not ALL messages are seen from subfolders, but just some of them have still their copies in the Inbox directory, although they were already moved by a rule in my Thunderbird working on the IMAP protocol. It seems to be related only to recent messages. Old mails are correctly synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved. I have to close Thunderbird to finalize moving messages on the server. This seems to be due to the fact, that messages during an IMAP session are only marked for deletion. They are actually deleted after disconnection.